# Data Factory DevOps SSIS-IntegrationRuntime

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

We're planning to use CI/CD pipelines for Data Factory. 
In one of our pipelines we use SSIS packages that needs to be called. To call SSIS packages you need to specify an Azure-SSIS IR that must be used.

[image]

The Azure-SSIS IR has a different naming on every environment.
Now, it is not possible to set this value dynamic (the option "Add dynamic content [Alt+P]" is not available on this field)
Is there a simple solution to change the Azure-SSIS IR during the deployment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your linked services aren't named by environment are they? (they most definitley should not be)

The default out of the box cloud runtime is *also* not named by environment.

*Your runtimes should not be named by environment either.*

IMHO your naming convention is incorrect. You should challenge it - there's no reason to include an environment designator in any runtime names.

Yes, your parent data factory should definitely have a different name per environment. That's where the distinction is made. Your runtimes should not.

In direct answer to your question, the way I have dealt with this in the past is added a powershell script task to the build part of DevOps that transforms the deployment asset and basically find/replaces the name the  delivers the result as a build artifact

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The naming was decided by an administrator, Dev and Test have the same name but for the production he has decided to give it a complete different name. Will try to ask for recreating a new SSIS IR withe the correct name, and else we will use PowerShell script

Comment: Last time I checked there was no simple rename capability. I'd expect you'd also need to repoint all of your pipelines as well.

Comment: Yes, we need to repoint all the pipelines as well that are using the SSIS IR, and that is not a nice job to do :)

Comment: You can theoretically just find and replace `ARMTemplateForFactory.json` and redeploy but it takes a little bit of experimenting